# How can I get the actual file in an <input type=file>, to be displayed in the <textarea> tag with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file-io, onchange

I have an input tag with type=file and I want to take the data it selects to display inside a textarea tag. I do not want to display just the file title but the entire file. Like how uploading attachments to emails before they are sent works.
How do I do this with javascript? There is no backend or server-side code in this work yet. I have tried to change the value but it only displayed the object type of the file to the textarea

```
let textfile = document.getElementById('file')
let textarea = document.getElementById('compose')
console.log(textarea);

textfile.addEventListener('change', (e) =>{
    let fil = e.target.files[0];

    if(fil){
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(fil);
    }

    textarea.value = fil 
})
```

Comment: You are almost there. You need to wait the `load` event of `FileReader` to get the `.result`, see the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Comment: @savageGoat I have done that just now but if I log the reader.result, I get the converted string. but how do I get it to upload the contents of the string to my textarea?

Comment: As I said, you are almost there. Place the `textarea.value =` inside the `load` callback. The `readAsDataURL` method is not synchronous, meaning that if you put `textarea.value = value` after the `FileReader.result` callback function, it won't work because the `load` event won't be resolved. If you put it inside the `load` function however, it will wait to get the result

Comment: @savageGoat thanks, i did that and now the output is taking the value of the text area, but it's a bunch of strings. how do i get it to upload the actual file, or is it a server problem?

Comment: You can't "upload" with file reader, you can just read the file. The contents you are getting are only displayed from your file to your html element through the browser. If you want to upload you'd need a technology like `ajax` or `fetch` with a backend server, and that is another discussion to have since it's not just HTML/javascript anymore

Comment: If you are trying to display an image please keep in mind that `<textarea>` will only display `text`, for an image you'd need the `<img/>` tag, and for anything else you'd need a reader adapted to your file format

Comment: thank you very much @savageGoat. You were very helpful, I now see the fault in my logic.

Comment: I think I see the problem. The only case you'd use `FileReader` here is if your email was stored inside a file, for anything else,`textarea` would be used to get the user input, and `files.length` to display the number of attached documents, and eventually the name of the file to display an icon according to the extension. You won't (in theory) need to read the files to send them to the server, you'd just send the files array without any processing

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

Using the `FileReader` `API`, So it will read the contents of the file and then you should add `onload` function to get the data only after the load of `FileReader`, then set the value property of the `textarea` element to the contents of the file.

```js
let textfile = document.getElementById('file');
let textarea = document.getElementById('compose');

textfile.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            textarea.value = e.target.result;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="file" id="file">
</div>
<div>
  <textarea id="compose" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me push the output to the textarea. I still have a problem though, the output data is a bunch of string, not the actual file that i selected, how do i do that

Comment: If I understand well what you mean, this solution is for files of text type (`.txt`, `.PHP`, `.HTML`, `.js`), If you try to read from a file like `docx` for example, the `docx` files are actually ZIP archives containing multiple files, including XML files that contain the contents of the document, So you will need extra operations to be able to read the content.

Comment: thank you. I think I that to get it to be displayed in the textarea i need a backend code. Also i think i am using the wrong tags.